# Block or stop loading a <img> tag and insert a new one in css

Tags: html, css

I have an `<img>` that I need to stop from showing. I do not have access to the HTML, only the CSS, unfortunately.

There is no class to the `<img>` as well.

Here is the HTML tag:

```
<img title="Manual" id="imgAjuda" src="images/ico_aj.png" width="16" height="16">
```

When I try to add the background `img` tag in the CSS of course it goes behind it, but I would love to use the CSS and block that `<img>` tag.

The CSS:

```
#imgAjuda {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-image: url(../images/MinhaConta.png) !important;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `display:none`?

Comment: Why not just #imgAjuda {display:none;} or #imgAjuda {visibility:hidden;}

Comment: Because I still need to use an image there from the css, I don't want the img and size be loaded from the html.

Comment: So basically the problem is that you can't access the HTML, but you want to replace the image with a different one, but your background image gets covered up by the image that's in the HTML?

Comment: Yes! :) that's my problem

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/ this should do the trick.

Comment: The above link requires a container div, am I right?

Comment: As is, you'll need a script. If you show us some more HTML/CSS, we might be able to suggest a CSS based solution.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question

this should work.

```
#imgAjuda {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-image: url(../images/MinhaConta.png) !important;
  display:none
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this proposed solution will remove the `img` tag from the DOM.

Comment: Yes, but thanks a lot guys! It is not possible, not the way it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging for a while and I cannot see how this is possible. However, I would like to explain why. There is only one target available to manipulate: `#imgAjuda`.

ANYTHING we do, be it opacity, image filters, or changes to width will also affect the `background-image` property.

Is there anything else you can tell us about the project that would allow us another variable to explore? Perhaps access to JavaScript, a server-side language, or a container `div`?

Comment: No, but thanks for the effort, it isn't possible. I had to use it.